# Electrum Doesn't Use Persistence in TAILS OS

Tags: tails, bitcoin

I've been trying to set up a BitCoin wallet in TAILS OS. Every time I enter into the Electrum application, I am warned that Electrum is not configured to use persistence on my USB, that I'll lose my wallet upon powering off. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As per [Tails documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/configure/index.en.html):

Go to `Applications` -> `Tails` -> `Configure Persistent Volume` then choose the option for `Bitcoin Client` then click on `Save` and reboot your Tails for the changes to take effect. Now Electrum should be using the Persistent volume.